# Passing String to a function that takes uint8_t in C

Tags: c, c-strings, pic, microchip, uint8t

I want to send a string over UART but the function that sends data over UART accepts `uint8_t` as an argument.

The function prototype: `UART2_Write(uint8_t txData);`

I wish to send an 8-character long string such as `"12345678"` and I have tried the following ways:

```
#define UID ("12345678")
UART2_Write(UID);
```

---

```
char UID[8] = "12345678";
UART2_Write(UID);
```

---

```
const char *UID = "12345678";
UART2_Write(UID);
```

---

Unfortunately, none of the above-mentioned methods yielded a successful result.

If there is a way to send a string in this situation, kindly let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you need to loop over all the characters in your string, calling `UART2_Write` multiple times, once for each character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending an entire 8-byte string in a single UART serial communication is not strictly possible, since UART sends data in blocks of 5-9 bits at a time. Based on the input parameter type of `UART2_Write()`, this transmission appears to be done in 8-bit mode. You must send each of the bytes in the string individually.

This can be done by looping over the characters in the string.

for instance:

```
for(size_t i = 0; UID[i] != '\0'; ++i)
  UART2_Write(UID[i]);
```

then, if the serial receiver is only expecting 8-bytes you're done, otherwise you may need to send a terminating character, like 0, which corresponds to NULL in ASCII, or perhaps you may want to send EOT (end of transmission), which corresponds to 0x4 in ASCII. To find out what you should send to signal that the transmission is over, you may need to read documentation on the device being communicated with via UART.

Comment: I see. On the receiver side, will the string appear as one continuous string? Or will it be one character at a time?

Comment: The receiver will get the string 1-byte at a time, but if it's expecting a string, that is how it will expect to receive it and it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Even modern internet connections work by sending data 1-byte at a time. This is just how digital connections tend to work

Comment: `strlen()` is redundant here. `size_t i = 0; do UART2_Write(UID[i]) while(UID[i++]);` Or `const char *s = UID; do UART2_Write(*s) while(*s++);` - if null terminator also must be sent.

Comment: This is true, but any compiler worth its weight in parmesan cheese is going to optimize `strlen(<macro that expands to a string>)` into an integer. It is definitely worth noting that neither `strlen()` nor the while loop @dimich suggests will work for the second example where the `char[]` is only 8-bytes long and therefore not null-terminated

Comment: It depends. If `UID` and printing function are defined in different compilation units at least link time optimization is required to eliminate `strlen()` call on every iteration.

Comment: That's not a bad point